# What are the combination in device token iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I want to know that device token is make with which type of combinations? What are structure of device token inside 64 hexa string.

Comment: Can you please clarify ? I could not understand your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "device token"? UDID?

Comment: Device token uses for apns.

Comment: Device Token - An identifier for the Apple Push Notification System for iOS devices. Each device has two device tokens (per app as of iOS 7)– one for development, and one for production (ad hoc or app store builds). The tokens are 64 hexadecimal characters

Comment: Source: http://mark.aufflick.com/files/view/talks/apns.pdf

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to are "push tokens". There are no "device tokens" and there are not only two of them.

See the following procedure (as you could already see in your posted slide deck):
- An app wants to register for push notifications.
- The user confirms in the UI that he wants to allow that.
- The app requests a new push token from Apple.

The last step is the important one: Apple assigns to this device AND app combination a unique push token.

If you've 253 apps on a device that use push notifications there'll be 253 unique push tokens.

Additionally:
The distinguishment you're talking about for "development" and "production" are the push gateways the developer registers for.